# Detect if filled area in canvas is circle shape

Tags: javascript, canvas

How can I detect if filled canvas is in shape of a Circle ?

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill();
```

This code draws circle with radius 50 and it's ok.
But how can I test  canvas later if it actually has a circle drow on it, and return true/false ? I suppose I need some math formulas/operations?

Comment: Are they created arbitrarily, or do you know when created they're circular? If the latter, keep track of the shape type e.g. `data-shape-type='circle'` and then you can query for them.

Comment: I am writing tests and i need to test the app and confirm if circle is added to the canvas.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but here's some tests written for Canteen that might point a way: https://github.com/platfora/Canteen/blob/master/test/all-tests.js